# choose k items from a set of x and y to meet certain criteria

Tags: algorithm, math, probability

I have given `x` and `y` items , I need to choose some `x` and some `y` with some constrain say `x < 10` and `y < 5` and the total number should be `p`.

How to solve such problem. Algorithm/ mathematical technique.

Comment: total number should be k or p?

Comment: I guess there is a deeper language problem here. Do you have x items, or values from (0 to x), the same for y? Does the number of items or the sum of their values have to be p? Do you need pairs (x+y) which sum up to p, or every combination (x1 + x2, ... + xn + y1, + y2 + ... + ym) = p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is we only need to go through one array (e.g. the x_array), and we can work out y using p-x=y. Now we only need to ensure y is in the y_array and we know we have our answer. To ensure y is in the y_array, we make a set or binary search tree for fast look-ups.

Here is some python code:

```
p=13
xs=[1,3,99,9,18]
ys=[10,4,33]

y_set=set(ys)

#y=p-x
results=((x,p-x) for x in xs if x<10 and p-x<5 and p-x in y_set)

print "x=%s,y=%s,p=13" % results.next()
'x=9,y=4,p=13'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
void main(void) {
     int x[] = {3, 5, 7, 10}
    int y[] = {5, 9, 12, 23}
    int i=0, j=0;
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            if (x[i]<10 && y[j]<5)
            {
                if(x[i]+y[j]==p)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No y is below 5. :) If you test x[i] < 10 before iterating over j, you might save much time for big x and y.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest algorithm I know will be :

1. Let `m` be the maximum of your constraints, and `z` the items constrained by `m`. In your case `m = 10, z = x`. This is because as m grows, p - m decreases.
2. I assume your items are generic. Create a map and associate the key `p - z[i].value()` to `z[i]`
3. Take each item `obj` in the other list (in your case `y`), and look if `obj.value()` is a key of your map. If it is, save both `obj.value()` and `map[obj.value()]`

Using the property of retrieving in a map in constant time `O(1)`, you have an algorithm which run in `O(sizeof(x)+sizeof(y))`